# Django admin drop down with very long description/text

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, format

just like the pic in admin panel when creating some post:
[image]

that basically one of dropdown menu options, it is so long, is there any idea on how i can change it to be multi-line? or maybe change the drop down menu to a "select table", the admin in this case need to read the description, so it is unwise for it to be formatted like that.
I have a code example:
models.py

```
class CreatePost(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=9000)
    isSolved = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a button
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="user_post")
    def __str__(self):
        return format_html('SUBJECT : {} <br/> DESCRIPTION : {}  <br/> Email : {} <br/> ',self.subject, self.desc, self.user.username)
    # remember to show the name of ticket sender


class RespondToPost(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(CreatePost,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to = models.EmailField(max_length=320)
    content = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return format_html('SUBJECT : {} <br/> DESCRIPTION : {} <br/> EMAIL : {} <br/> ',self.post.subject, self.post.desc, self.post.user.username)
```

admin.py

```
class CreatePostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', '__str__')
    class Meta:
        model = models.CreatePost

class RespondToPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', '__str__', 'to', 'content')
    class Meta:
        model = models.RespondToPost
```

any idea?

Comment: Default drop-downs do not support multiline text. You should create a shorter `__str__()`.

Comment: how is that related to description being long, shorter `__str__()` wont solve the issue

Comment: Where do you think the description comes from?

Comment: the user, but in database context it is part of Post model, and the admin need to see it as i described.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom field to `list_display` and change its content however you like:

```
from django.utils.text import Truncator  # for shortening a text


class CreatePostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'get_truncated_str')

    class Meta:
        model = models.CreatePost

    def get_truncated_str(self, obj):
        # Change it however you want, shortening is just an example
        return Truncator(str(obj)).words(10)
```

Comment: as i said in the question, `the admin need to read the description`, so shortening it is not a solution

Comment: @Ghazi I gave you an idea of how you can customize some field, and given that you can do it however you want in the method: make it multiline or shorten or whatever

Comment: sorry, i must missed the idea, how is your code produce the solution of multiline for description?